# Remove Gaps Between Links In Unordered List

Tags: css, hyperlink, hover, html-lists, mouseover

This has to be something ridiculously simple, but I'm just not seeing it, and would appreciate a bit of advice.

I applied CSS to make different images appear when mouse hovers over different links. One of the images is there by default, being the part of the background jpg image. All the other images appear only when the mouse hovers over corresponding link.

**Problem:** when I slide the cursor left and right along the row of links, or top and bottom vertically, there are gaps between the links, approximately 4px or so. When the cursor is over the gap, links are ineffective, so no image appears on top, and the background image is revealed, creating a sort of flicker.

**Question:** how can I remove the gaps between links, keeping the background image visible only when the cursor hovers over its link, but nowhere else?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of that little gap is because if you have a line break or multiple spaces between two elements, the browser will collapse all that to one space. Exactly the space you are seeing.

What you need to do is the following (I know the markup looks ugly):

```
<div id="hero-links-container">
<ul> 
    <li>
        <a href="" id="hero-link-pianos"><div id="hero-image-piano"></div>Pianos</a><a href="" id="hero-link-woodwinds"><div id="hero-image-woodwinds"></div>Woodwinds</a><a href="" id="hero-link-percussion"><div id="hero-image-percussion"></div>Percussion</a><a href="" id="hero-link-music-education"><div id="hero-image-music-education"></div>Music Education</a><a href="" id="hero-link-brasswinds"><div id="hero-image-brasswinds"></div>Brasswinds</a><a href="" id="hero-link-strings"><div id="hero-image-strings"></div>Strings</a><a href="" id="hero-link-accessories"><div id="hero-image-accessories"></div>Accessories</a><a href="" id="hero-link-recorded-music"><div id="hero-image-recorded-music"></div>Recorded Music</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This partially solves the problem, @Kenneth, but not fully. Could you please take a look, I updated the site as you suggested, thank you. Horizontally it works, but there are still vertical gaps, and the piano image is revealed when the mouse hovers over them.

Comment: The vertical gap is a problem with the line height and the fact that you are vertically aligning the text to the baseline. A few solutions: set the padding-top of the links to 5px => this will increase the height or set the vertical-align to "top".